# Modeling the formation of a stellar system and matter accretion

Tags: gravity, fluid-dynamics, electrostatics, astrophysics, simulations

I am trying to figure out what do I need to know to properly simulate the creation of a solar system from a particle cloud with random distribution of hydrogen atoms.

Being more of a programming background than a physicist one, I find some difficulties trying to find all the forces in interaction.

As for now, I'm looking to simulate the accretion of matter in a random distribution of particles in a void space. I can successfully identify gravitational effects, and have included them as mutual interaction between every particle in my system. I am computing this by summing the effect of every other particle on each one iteratively, and applying the resulting acceleration to the said particle, and so on.

This approach is limited to small numbers of particles and it's fine for me now, because I don't go over 1000 particles per simulation. However, the trouble is that I also want to include other forces that may be playing a significant role in this process. I'm thinking specifically of electric interaction, as I am not yet in the step of simulating eventual nuclear interactions.

I'm not sure how to approach it and I'm fairly confused.

How electric force is involved in my scenario? How can I account for it in my calculations?

Specifically, in a cloud of hydrogen particles in space, what is happening?

Comment: In your question you mention Hydrogen.  If you only plan on simulating hydrogen you don't need to work about charge since Hydrogen is neutral.

Comment: If the electric force is dismissed, it's accurate to account only for gravitation to simulate the dynamics of the particles ?

Comment: By way of orientation, the computational issues (and there are easy ways to improve on the naive model you are using) are off-topic here and belong on [the scientific computation](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) site; the *physics* that occurs in these circumstance are on-topic. You are missing many things, such as the presence of dust and the physics with which such things stick together. I would not be surprised if you are using a naive (non-[symplectic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator)) update algorithm, which you will want to fix. There are some questions on SciComp.

Comment: @dmckee I am actually trying to explore ways to compute the system dynamics and comparing efficiency. I update the positions using a simple euler method and while it is not very accurate, it provides me with a basis to explore the physical question, and improve my algorithm later on, probably basing it on some existing library.
However, my question here was specifically focused on the physics involved in a hydrogen cloud.

Comment: With a good integrator a simple set of gravitation interactions can't lose energy (though it can cool by ejecting some of the particles). You'll want a radiation mechanism as the gas warms.

Comment: What is the name of the warming process ?
Can you point me to the general direction of what I need to study ?